# Tie enum to multiple integers

Tags: c#, enums

Lets say that i have this example enum:

```cs
public enum Enum
    {
        A,
        B
    }
```

Is it possible to tie it with multiple integers? Example: `enum` `A` will be tied to `1` and `2`, `enum` `B` to `3` and `4`.

```cs
Enum example = (Enum)1;
Console.WriteLine(example);
//A

example = (Enum)3;
Console.WriteLine(example);
//B
```

Edit

Dictionary is acceptable equivalent. Problem solved.

Comment: @TheGeneral that might be possible, but i can't see alternative.

Comment: You can use attributes and associate the numbers with enums, or you could use a dictionary of list ect. Though you cant actually have an enum value with 2 numbers. `A` cant equal 1 and 2 in any simple sense.. however you can have multiple enums point to the same number

Comment: If you create a `[Flags]` enum, you can encode multiple values into a single enum, but not in the way you describe.  Consider `[Flags] enum Days {Sunday=0x01, Monday=0x02, Tuesday=0x04, Wednesday=0x08, Thursday=0x10, Friday=0x20, Saturday=0x40, Weekends=Sunday|Saturday, Weekdays=Monday|Tuesday|Wednesday|Thursday|Friday, AllDay=Weekends|Weekdays}`.  Each day is a separate bit, combinations are created by OR-ing those bits into a specific bit-pattern.  You can figure out the bit patterns by using the `&` and `|` bit-logical operators

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not natively as part of the language. An enum member is an alias to a single integer value. Multiple enum members can be aliases for the same numeric value (so you can have `D = 1` and `F = 1`), but one alias is only one number.

You could use some other mechanism (attributes, or a simple lookup function) to do this yourself. But at that point, it probably isn't really an "enum" in the language sense, so it might be better to just use an integer.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I was talking about in the comments (about using a `[Flags]` enum).  Consider an enum that looks like:

```
[Flags]
public enum Days
{
    Sunday = 0x01, 
    Monday = 0x02, 
    Tuesday = 0x04, 
    Wednesday = 0x08, 
    Thursday = 0x10, 
    Friday = 0x20, 
    Saturday = 0x40, 
    Weekends = Sunday | Saturday, 
    Weekdays = Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday, 
    AllDays = Weekends | Weekdays
}
```

The days of the week entries each represent a single day.  They are distinguished by a bit pattern that has exactly one bit set.  The entries like `Weekends`, `Weekdays` and `AllDays` represent multiple values.

You can use them in functions like this:

```
public static bool IsWeekend(Days dayOfWeek)
{
    return (int)(dayOfWeek & Days.Weekends) != 0;
}

public static bool IsWeekday(Days dayOfWeek)
{
    return (int)(dayOfWeek & Days.Weekdays) != 0;
}
```

Both of those could be *extension methods* on the `Days` enumerated type if you'd like.

You can also get fancier like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetWeekdays()
{
    var allDays = (Days[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(Days));
    foreach (var day in allDays)
    {
        if (IsWeekday(day) && IsOnlyOneBitSet(day))
        {
            yield return day.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

But you need a helper function like this (to make sure you only consider single day entries in the output, not the combined entries (like `Weekdays`):

```
private static bool IsOnlyOneBitSet(Days dayOfWeek)
{
    var asInt = (int) dayOfWeek;
    return asInt != 0 && (asInt & (asInt - 1)) == 0;
}
```

I'm not sure that this is what you are looking for, but I figure it might help you out.

If you call the `GetWeekdays` function, you get a collection that looks like this in the debugger:

```
    [0] "Monday"    string
    [1] "Tuesday"   string
    [2] "Wednesday" string
    [3] "Thursday"  string
    [4] "Friday"    string
```